# How to create an android application by explicitly creating AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-manifest, manifest

I want to create an android application on the android studio from scratch without using the auto xml layout(AndroidManifest.xml) file generation and rather explicitly creating it by myself.

Comment: Um, `AndroidManifest.xml` is not an "auto xml layout".

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that, what i mean to say is how to prevent it from auto creation and explicitly create that file!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just right click res folder -> New -> Android Resource file, that is how you make an xml file explicitly and than you can include it in the java file!!

Comment: also how to avoid it from making in the project by itself?

Comment: You cant avoid the generation of AndroidManifest.xml, but you can always edit the file as you like.

Comment: Yes you can, @sagar , by simply NOT creating a project using the wizard

Answer (score 1):

Using the new-project wizard will create an `AndroidManifest.xml` file for you, as all projects need one. If you do not want Android Studio to create an  `AndroidManifest.xml` for you, do not use the new-project wizard.

Instead, you will need to create all of the project files yourself, either by hand or by some other tool that you find or create. Then, import the project into Android Studio, if you wish to use the IDE to further manipulate the project files.